# How can I get to the Sinking Tombs?

Tags: mobius-final-fantasy

In Chapter 2 of Möbius Final Fantasy, there are several paths between battles that are blocked off. In most cases, I can either find a key or go around the long way and get to the blocked area.

However, the portion of the map labeled Sinking Tombs does not appear to have a back path. As you can see, I've completely encircled it, but the only road in is blocked. Unlike unlockable roadblocks, where a key or later action will open up access, this road displays an **X**. It does not tell me what key I need to find, as the locks do, it simply says "you cannot go this way. You must find another route."

[image: Map screenshot]

How do I get to the tombs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go through Sinner's Hovel.
[Sinking Tombs http://puu.sh/qsG0f.png](http://puu.sh/qsG0f.png)